# How to solve "noHandlerFound" in Spring MVC with Java based configuration?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I am developing Spring MVC application with Java based configuration. I am facing this error `org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet noHandlerFound` and `WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/solution/clients/css/form.css] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher'`

AppConfig.java

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@EnableTransactionManagement
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "solution")
@PropertySource("classpath:persistence-mysql.properties")
public class AppConfig {
    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    private Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(getClass().getName());

    @Bean
    public ViewResolver viewResolver() {

        InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();

        viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/view/");
        viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");

        return viewResolver;
    }
}
```

SolutionDispatcherServletInitializer.java

```
public class SolutionDispatcherServletInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[] { AppConfig.class };
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[] { "/" };
    }
}
```

Controller class:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/clients")
public class ClientsController {

    // Injection of Service Class
    @Autowired
    private ClientService clientService;

    @GetMapping("/list")
    public String listClients(Model theModel) {

        // Getting Clients From SERVICE Class
        List<Clients> theClients = clientService.getClients();

        // Adding Clients to Model(Entity Class) 
        theModel.addAttribute("clientsModel", theClients);

        return "list-clients";
    }   
}
```

View:

```
<h3>ALL CLIENTS</h3>
  <div class="addnew-form">

  <table>
     <tr>
        <th class="trtd">First Name</th>
        <th class="trtd">Last Name</th>
        <th class="trtd">Email</th>
        <th class="trtd">Mobile Number</th>
        <th class="trtd">City</th>
        <th class="trtd">Country</th>
        <th class="trtd">Domain</th>
        <th class="trtd">View</th>
        <th class="trtd">Action</th>
     </tr>

     <!-- LOOP -->

     <c:forEach var="tempClients" items="${clientsModel}">
     <tr>
       <td class="trtd">${tempClients.firstName}</td>
       <td class="trtd">${tempClients.lastName}</td>
       <td class="trtd">${tempClients.email}</td>
       <td class="trtd">${tempClients.mobileNumber}</td>
       <td class="trtd">${tempClients.city}</td>
       <td class="trtd">${tempClients.country}</td>
       <td class="trtd">${tempClients.domain}</td>
     </tr>
     </c:forEach>
  </table>
```

Error Messages:

```
May 31, 2019 12:40:22 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet noHandlerFound
WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/solution/clients/css/form.css] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher'
WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/solution/$%7BpageContext.request.contextPath%7D/clients/list] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher'
```

The Output on Web browser looks something like this. My Database has connectivity with the application. But still not getting data from MySql. The output displays some JSP code. `${tempClients.firstName}`

Image:[Click here for Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7tbAc.png)

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Do you have a Model and Controller? You define and provide the model to the view (jsp) in the controller. Also you need some type of resource handlers for your static files like css.

Comment: Of course, I have an Entity class and Controller class, without it application won't run on the server.

Comment: Can you add the controller and view to your question please? It would help us help you.

Comment: Added Controller and View.

Comment: 1> for this warning /solution/clients/css/form.css you need a resource handler for this.
2> Do you have JSTL library in your classpath and imported on JSP?

Comment: Yes, I do have added JSTL dependencies in my pom.xml file, Secondly, CSS problem can be solved by me. Please review the Image that will help you to understand more. I have redirected "list-client" page in Index file, if I manually do like, "${pageContext.request.contextPath}/clients/list" this will throw 404 error. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to change @Controller annotation to @RestController.

So your controller will be like

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/clients")
public class ClientsController {

    // Injection of Service Class
    @Autowired
    private ClientService clientService;

    @GetMapping("/list")
    public String listClients(Model theModel) {

        // Getting Clients From SERVICE Class
        List<Clients> theClients = clientService.getClients();

        // Adding Clients to Model(Entity Class) 
        theModel.addAttribute("clientsModel", theClients);

        return "list-clients";
    }   
}
```

Comment: This is a spring application, not RESTful API. Thanks anyway. I found the solution. `<%@ page isELIgnored="false" %>` this was missing. Thanks anyway.